# Using mod_rewrite to hide tomcat port

Tags: tomcat, mod-rewrite, port, rewrite

I have apps on Tomcat that use URLs like this: `http://xxx:8080/myapp`

I don't want the users to see the port in the URL.

Hi can do a rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/myapp(.*) http://xxx:8080/myapp$1 [P,L]
```

This way, if a user goes to the URL `http://xxx/myapp` he can enter the app fine, but the port will still show up on the browser. I want the URL that the user sees to be always `http://xxx/myapp`

How can I do this using mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reverse proxy in Apache.

Create a VirtualHost which is listen on 80 port and setup proxy:

```
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass / http://xxx:8091/app/
ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx:8091/app/
```

Comment: This was the solution I used. But, I used the rules like this:
`ProxyPass /webapp http://xxx:8080/webapp/
ProxyPassReverse /webapp http://xxx:8080/webapp/`
With the generic rule `ProxyPass / http://xxx:8091/app/` it conflicts with the hosts I had on Apache.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any other web server listening on port 80 like apache, a simple solution will be to change the listening port of tomcat to be 80.

If you have apache listening on port 80, you can still access your apps on port 80 using mod_jk.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is via a **reverse** proxy.

You can setup another web server in front of tomcat that acts as a reverse proxy and automatically does the translations between port 80 at the front and port 8080 at the back.

Apache can be configured using *mod_proxy* or even *mod_jk* and/or *mod_proxy_ajp*. Otherwise, you can use standalone proxies such as *pound*.